# How to do TOS/DSCP in ruby?

Tags: ruby, tcp, udp, stream, qos

How does one set the [TOS flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_Service)/[DSCP flags](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2474) in Ruby on a UDP/TCP stream
(preferably using the Ruby/Sockets library)?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the TOS flags with [Socket.setsockopt](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#method-i-setsockopt) passing `IPPROTO_IP` as the level, `IP_TOS` as the name of the option, and your desired value:

```
require 'socket'
s = TCPSocket.new('example.com', 80)
s.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_TOS, YOUR_TOS_VAL)
```

Comment: This works on Linux. 
Thanks so far, 
but would there also be something similar for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try Socket#setsockoption().  Its documented in Appendix A of the pickaxe book, or you can browse the source for interface details.

-- MarkusQ